# Git rebase showing errors, screwing up the rebased log

Tags: git

Having run the following commands:

```
git init
touch README 
git add README
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
git branch b01_02_03
git checkout b01_02_03
echo "Data 1" >> f1 && git add f1 && git commit -m "Add 01"
echo "Data 2" >> f2 && git add f2 && git commit -m "Add 02"
echo "Data 3" >> f3 && git add f3 && git commit -m "Add 03"
git checkout master
git branch b04_05 
git checkout b04_05
echo "Data 4" >> f4 && git add f4 && git commit -m "Add 04"
echo "Data 5" >> f5 && git add f5 && git commit -m "Add 05"
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only b01_02_03
git checkout b04_05
```

to form the following test tree:

```
* 8294414 (HEAD, b04_05) add 05
* 19f920f add 04
| * 3a2ca64 (master, b01_02_03) add 03
| * 49d1aca add 02
| * c8f6d30 add 01
|/  
* 7f0ca8e initial commit
```

I'm running

```
git rebase master
```

and getting the following output.

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: add 04
/opt/swt/install/git-1.7.12.3/libexec/git-core/git-am: line 115: /home9/tclarke/git-puzzles-1/.git/rebase-apply/next: cannot overwrite existing file
/opt/swt/install/git-1.7.12.3/libexec/git-core/git-am: line 665: 1: cannot overwrite existing file
/opt/swt/install/git-1.7.12.3/libexec/git-core/git-am: line 666: 1: cannot overwrite existing file
/opt/swt/install/git-1.7.12.3/libexec/git-core/git-am: line 712: 1: cannot overwrite existing file
Applying: add 04
/opt/swt/install/git-1.7.12.3/libexec/git-core/git-am: line 115: /home9/tclarke/git-puzzles-1/.git/rebase-apply/next: cannot overwrite existing file
```

The result is:

```
* c88b1f0 (HEAD, b04_05) add 04
* 761c779 add 04
* 3a2ca64 (master, b01_02_03) add 03
* 49d1aca add 02
* c8f6d30 add 01
* 7f0ca8e initial commit
```

Successful rebase, but the logs are screwed up, log "add 05" becomes identical to its predecessor. This is repeatable on a different machine in a different filespace, on a fresh git repository that I've created. My neighbour doesn't get the same problem with an identical tree.

Any advice on how to resolve this?

Comment: have you checked if this is not just a simple file permission problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is just that. The weird bit is the file in question: /home9/tclarke/git-puzzles-1/.git/rebase-apply/next seems to be being created and destroyed by the rebase itself, so it simply doesn't exist when I try and check its permissions.

Comment: What is your umask set to?  Is it possible you are taking away your own write permission for files (e.g., a umask of 0222 for instance)?

Comment: umask 0002, so that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions for some of the repo meta-files could be wrong, for some reason.

First, try running `chmod -R u+rw .git` in the local repo's main path (`/home9/tclarke/git-puzzles-1`), then see if the rebase works. (Even if it does, do the next step as well).

Next, make sure the remote repo was initialized as shared. On the remote location of the repo (you need shell access for this), look at the `config` file and whether, under the `[core]` section, you have this line:

```
sharedrepository = 1
```

If it's missing, add it, then run `chmod -R g+w /path/to/repo` (and add `denyNonFastforwards = true` under `[receive]` as well).

Last, make sure no other processes have locked your local repo's meta-files (can't think of a reason this would happen, but still). Run `lsof | grep -F /home9/tclarke/git-puzzles-1/.git` and see if you come up with anything.

Comment: Ah, thing I should have mentioned, this is entirely within my local repo (I'm trying out a rebasing exercise).

Comment: @deworde You mentioned a fresh checkout on a different machine, and that it works for your neighbor. So you do have a remote repo you're cloning from?

Comment: I see what you mean. It's a --bare clone and we then re-init and strip out the remotes, so it's basically getting us to the point where it's just a repo in a known state, but with no connection to the original source.

I should give this a go with a genuinely self-made local in the same state to see if I get the same effect.

Comment: @deworde Are you trying this directly on the bare repo? Running git commands directly in a bare repo isn't always a good idea - if the command requires a working tree (and `rebase` does), it will not work as expected.

Comment: To make sure that wasn't it, I literally git inited on a new folder and built the above tree from scratch. Same problem.

Comment: Tried these solutions, no effect.